Find Overdue Dates for Each Resource within a Task that has Multiple Resources Assigned
I have projects that have multiple resources assigned to tasks.  I created a macro to find overdue tasks, unfortunately, it only considers the task finish date, which, may be different for some of the resources assigned to that task.  Please see image below.  With the macro I can find the task finish date (1); however, the finish dates for each resource within that task (2) can be different.  Is there a way to check finish dates for each resource within a task?  Thanks in advance for any and all help!


Look at the Finish date of the Assignment object, which is in the collection of the Assignments for the task.
For example: tsk.Assignments(2).Finish has a finish date of 3/12/24 in your example.

Hi Rachel, thank you for the information. :-)
